# Effect on call activity. (intent)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've seen in applications like facebook, that intent to call a do a screen effect that goes from the bottom up, or left to right or top to bottom ...

I searched and I could not find as anyone knows how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemPage.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

slide in left xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

slide out left xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply so fast ... but I have another question, how do I make it from the bottom up and vice versa?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, whit this.
android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p"

but, this effect is fast!, as I can make it slower? You can put something more than those 3 options config_longAnimTime, config_shortAnimTime, and config_medium?AnimTime?

Comment: these are just predefined by android, you can put in any long time in milliseconds I believe.